# How to Generate WSDL file and Create a Web Service with PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I want to create a simple web service that takes two numbers as parameters, and returns the result of multiplying the two numbers on localhost. 
I'm using php with apache server (xampp), and I couldn't find a good, or understandable way for that matter, to generate a wsdl file for this web service, so can you tell any good way for that? Plus, which SOAP functions I need to use?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'd stay away of soap combination unless it's a strict requirement to build your web service on top of it.

Comment: Consider looking at REST as well. There's sure to be tutorials out there if you search for "REST service PHP example".

Comment: Actually yes, its a requirement.